# How to install libgdal1-dev

Tags: r, ubuntu, gdal, rgdal

I'm in trouble installing rgdal packages in R. I'm using R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) on a computer with:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 17.04

Release:    17.04

Codename:   zesty

The problem is actually that I can't run on my console.

$ sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev

It gives me a lot of 'NOT FOUND' I really don't know what to do in this situation.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try just `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev` (without the 1)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately same result

Comment: Err:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libmysqlclient-dev amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 hdf5-helpers amd64 1.10.0-patch1+docs-3
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libarmadillo7 amd64 1:7.600.2+dfsg-2
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libarpack2-dev amd64 3.4.0-1build1
  404  Not Found

Comment: this is an example of what i get

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` before installing.

Comment: This would be better posted on askubuntu.com since it's about ubuntu package management rather than programming. (The answer you've got might well be right though)

Comment: I still have the same problem, when i try to run sudo apt-get update this is the result: Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:4 http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ InRelease        
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

Comment: In case, you would like to do this in the future, I wrote a blog article about installing spatial packages on Ubuntu. This may help some: https://rtask.thinkr.fr/blog/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes the support for Zesty ended in January. You have to update to Artful, c.f.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.04.

Comment: Could be a problem with my internet connection? i'm in Saudi Arabia and there will be a possibility that i can't access to the repository?

Comment: @FrancescoSerafini Zesty is not among the distributions listed in http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, so I do not think your internet connection is causing the problems. However, this question is indeed more suited for https://askubuntu.com/.